# __HAL_TIM_GetCounter with STM32F103

Tags: stm32, timer, hal-library

I found a lot of tutorial to get counter value from an interrupt timer
something like:

```
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  count = __HAL_TIM_GetCounter(&htim2);    //read TIM2 counter value
/* USER CODE END WHILE */
```

Generally, this code is used with HAL libraries and STM32F4
I used the same but the function is not declared in HAL Libraries.
Do you know why? What I'm supposed to use instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It was:
__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER

I should RTFM better

Answer (score 1):

`__HAL_TIM_GetCounter()` is apparently deprecated and moved to `Legacy/stm32_hal_legacy.h`. If you have a lot of old code, you can put `#define USE_LEGACY` in `stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h` to include it automatically.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, go *stm32fXxx_hal_tim.h* file. And then you can look whatever you want to function.  In my header file, *__HAL_TIM_GetCounter*  function updated as **__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER**

I think you can use that function.

Comment: Of course the OP can use that function, they already posted it in an answer more than one year ago.